# Very Simple xml to linq query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am new to Linq to XML (new to Linq period)

I have a very simple XML structure (I could just parse it manually, but I want to learn linq to xml).

here is my code:

```
XElement approvalRequest = XElement.Load(xml);
string emailTo = (string)(approvalRequest.Descendants("to").First().Value);
```

This throws

> Invalid Operation Exception:  Sequence contains no values

However,

```
string emailTo = (string) (approvalRequest.Descendants().First().Value)
```

returns the expected result (since 'to' is the first element)

Here is the value of `approvalRequest` (as queried in C# Watch)

```
<email xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
  <to>:approver_email</to>
  <from>:my_email</from>
  <subject>:rm Code Review</subject>
  <body>
    Hi :approver_first_name
    
    Please review the code for :rm.  All modules are in SCM/MDSS/UAT/:rm
    
    Thanks,
    :my_name
    :my_email
    
  </body>
  <attachments></attachments>
</email>
```

It seems this should be stupid simple. I must be missing something basic.

I have also tried getting at it with an actual linq query but always get null.

Also from Watch expanding `approvalRequest.Descendants()` yields:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML has a default namespace: `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"`.

It means that each and every XML element is bound to it. Even if it is not visible explicitly.

Please find below how to handle it.

I am just using `.Parse()` method for convenience instead of `.Load()` method from a file.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<email xmlns='http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd'>
        <to>:approver_email</to>
        <from>:my_email</from>
        <subject>:rm Code Review</subject>
        <body>Hi :approver_first_name
        
        Please review the code for :rm.  All modules are in SCM/MDSS/UAT/:rm
        
        Thanks,
        :my_name
        :my_email</body>
        <attachments></attachments>
    </email>");

    XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    string emailTo = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "to").FirstOrDefault().Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Yitzhak Khabinsky has mentioned the problem with your approach is that you are ignoring the fact that your xml has a default namespace.

As alternative to his approach you can use the `LocalName` ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xname.localname?view=net-5.0)) field of the `XName` class.

```cs
var parsedXml = XDocument.Load("sample.xml");
var toValue = parsedXml.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name.LocalName == "to")?.Value;
Console.WriteLine(toValue);
```

- With `Descendants` you retrieve all the nodes as `XElement`s
- Each `XElement` has a property called `Name` with `XName` type
- Each `XName` has a `LocalName` and a `Namespace` properties

You can do your check against the `LocalName` or against the `ToString` (as Yitzhak Khabinsky suggested). The `ToString` is [overriden](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/08b84d13e81cfdbd769a557b368539aac6a9cb30/System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs#L75) in the following way:

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    if (_ns.NamespaceName.Length == 0) return _localName;
    return "{" + _ns.NamespaceName + "}" + _localName;
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter.  Thanks.  Your comments around Descendents/Xname/LocalName, etc.  were most enlightening.  I used @Yitzhak Khabinsky's solution, as it seemed to me to be more straightforward.